# Excel; how to combine left and right functions

Tags: excel, function

I have a column of text values that I want to delete the first 8 and last 4 characters from i.e '12345678john1234' would just become 'john'. I know how to use the left and right functions separately but can't seem to get them working together. The mid function won't work in this case. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: _The mid function won't work in this case._  Isn't `=MID(a1,9,LEN(a1)-12)` what you need?

Comment: Would this still work if all of the values are different lengths?

Comment: Yes, as long as you always want to delete 8 first and 4 last chars.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with:

=MID(a1,9,LEN(a1)-12)

Explaination:

```
MID: get the middle string
=MID(text,start_nums,numchars)
start_nums = 9 to start from the character j
numchars = len(text)-12 = 16 - 12 = 4
```

Then you will get the result as john

Comment: While this post may answer the question it is still better to include some additional explanations and, possibly, references to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Dear Use this formula and you can get your answer

=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,8),4)